# Heroku and Godaddy don't want working together

Tags: domain-name-system, heroku

1) I have an app on heroku.com, code-w.herokuapp.com (works fine). 2)I have a domain, that I bought: gamakers.org. 3)I have done all that described in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125175/setup-heroku-and-godaddy

4) I have got no result. When I open gamakers.com, it says:

This website is temporarily unavailable, please try again later.

Meanwhile, I can see my favicon is loaded.
Next when I open www.gamakers.com, it says:

Bad Request (400).

P.S: I discussed the problem on GoDaddy with their support, they said: If Heroku can't give you static IP of the site, we can't help you. But documentation on heroku.com says, we DO not use static IP for our apps, we use only URL. So, I took my url from Heroku CLI and put it on Godaddy. No results. Please, who has heroku + GoDaddy site working fine right now, help me. Thanks.

---

UPDATE
I tried what you said(thanks to all)but - no results. Here are my settings on screens below:
[my results (BAD request 400)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb271.png)
[My heroku dashboard dns urls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6b6K.png)
[my Godaddy DNS settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/timBF.png)
[my Godaddy forwarding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IaeN.png)

+1 UPDATE:
Thanks for your help, obviously GoDaddy now is working along with heroku DNS, because I can see all logs appearing in my Heroku logs. Now it's time to ask question on Heroku.

Comment: Check your app logs. The `www.gamakers.com` domain points as CNAME to `code-w.herokuapp.com` correctly. Probably your app isn't configured to handle your `www.gamakers.com` domain.

Comment: I have checked the logs, here are no any requests, whileas I do them.. In my app I have this: gamakers.org      ALIAS or ANAME   gamakers.org.herokudns.com
www.gamakers.org  CNAME www.gamakers.org.herokudns.com

Comment: When I do `dig www.gamakers.org` it returns `CNAME code-w.herokuapp.com.`

Comment: (I do show you put a redirect from non-www to www successfully, though.)

Comment: The "Bad Request (400)" appears to be coming from Heroku.

Comment: Now that you've got the DNS apparently set up right - I show `www.gamakers.org. IN CNAME www.gamakers.org.herokudns.com.` now - you'll want to contact Heroku asking why it's 400ing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to set up the non-www variant of the domain to the www variant. GoDaddy has something for this (just make sure you're doing it only to the non-www record): https://ph.godaddy.com/help/manually-forward-or-mask-your-domain-or-subdomain-422

Second, you can't just CNAME to your app's herokuapp.com subdomain. You need to add the app in your app's Settings in the Heroku dashboard, then CNAME to the **specific** address you're provided with there.

It'll look like this:

[image]

That `www.gamakers.com.herokudns.com` is what you want to put as the CNAME's value. **Don't just use what I got** - they may give you a *different* target value, I don't know.